# Do multiple goroutine will invoke a method on a Conn simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, networking, go, goroutine

My program like this:

```
func handle(conn net.Conn) {
    msg := "hello, world!"
    for i:= 0; i< 100000; i++ {
        go func() {
            err := write(conn, msg)
        }
    }

}
func write(conn net.Conn, msg string) error {
    mlen := fmt.Sprintf("%04d", len(msg))

    _, err := conn.Write([]byte(mlen + msg))
    return err
}
```

The program will run 100000 goroutines at same time, and all goroutines will send message to the same connection。
I am doubt that server will receive error message like "hellohelloworldworld", but there is no problem when the program run in my Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

So, Do multiple goroutine will invoke a method on a Conn simultaneously?

=========================================================================

How can I keep the `Write` method atomic?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation states:

> Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously.

There is no mention of whether each individual write is atomic. While the current implementation may ensure that each call to `Write` happens completely before the next call can begin, there is no guarantee in the language specification.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38588711/152580) implies writes are atomic.

Specifically implementors of the io.Write interface are required to return an error if a partial write occurs. net.Conn handles this on unix by acquiring a lock and calling write in a loop until the whole buffer is written. On Windows it calls WSASend which guarantees to send the whole buffer unless an error occurs. But the docs do [have this warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasend):

> The order of calls made to WSASend is also the order in which the
> buffers are transmitted to the transport layer. WSASend should not be
> called on the same stream-oriented socket concurrently from different
> threads, because some Winsock providers may split a large send request
> into multiple transmissions, and this may lead to unintended data
> interleaving from multiple concurrent send requests on the same
> stream-oriented socket.

Which means it wouldn't necessarily be atomic, unless Go acquires a mutex - [which it does](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e97d8eb027c0067f757860b6f766644de15941f2/src/internal/poll/fd_windows.go#L598).

So basically it is atomic in practice. It is conceivable that an implementation could define thread-safety as just not crashing and allow interleaved writes by unlocking the mutex around calls to write (or not acquiring it at all on windows.) That doesn't make sense to me though, and the developers have clearly shown the opposite intent.